# Copyright/property rights to using the Certificate 18 movie logo on your game or artwork without permission?

Tags: copyright, trademark, intellectual-property

Ok so I have been making a game recently just for fun and might be making it available for download. I have done it in the past with ERSB (or whatever it called) and they give the official age rating of the game

But I want to use the Certificate 18 movie logo that has been used for decades , on my games title screen. With some kind of tagline such as "This is not for kids!"

Is that legal?  or is it in breach of any kind of law?

Sorry if this is off-topic, I did a search but can't find the answer anywhere. I figured you knowledgable beauties would know the answer!!

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/what-classification/18)?

Comment: I don't know whether it's _legal_, but I would advance that it's wrong. Why would you tag a _game_ with something made for a _movie_? This seems deceiving for the customer. Also, keep in mind that these logos are attributed by government agencies, and thus depend on the region in which they're used. Using the official logo used in the UK will not mean a thing for players living in french Canada.

Comment: It was just for a visual affect, and a joke on the games landing page. It was not meant to look officical. But I see that it would would cause problems as described in pikalek's answer

Comment: My answer was targeting usage that could be mistaken as official application. I'm not addressing how to use / modify things in order to constitute parody application & that might be more relevant to your situation - if so, you might want to edit to clearly reflect that & re-open the question.

Comment: Thanks guys. But I decided against it for now. Perhaps I can just make a mock version one day. BTW I noticed one of my only boxed games, Red Dead Redemption on Xbox 360 has the 18 Certificate on my copy purchased here in the UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legally, the short answer is no, you cannot just use them. Using their labelling suggest that they have vetted & rated your product, which is presently not the case. They regulate [usage their labeling](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/industry-services/using-ratings) in an attempt to achieve the following:

> BBFC age ratings (text and symbols) are identifiable, understandable,
>   trusted and consistent in their application and meaning.
>
> Using them allows viewers to make safe, informed decisions about the
>   content they choose for themselves and their family.
>
> In order for them to retain their value to the public, BBFC age
>   ratings must be used in a consistent and correct fashion.

Additionally, their [classification guidelines](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/sites/default/files/attachments/BBFC%20Classification%20Guidelines%202014_4.pdf) state:

> With a few limited exceptions we do not classify video games.

Details of how and where BBFC symbols can be used are covered in their [licensing agreement](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/sites/default/files/attachments/BBFC%20Digital%20Licence_1.pdf); if you want to get into particulars about it, you should either read through with a lawyer &/or contact them as described on their [other uses page](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/industry-services/using-ratings/other-uses).